# How to make one IBAction that does the same action to two buttons when the first one is from a custom cell and the other one is from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, custom-cell

This is from the custom cell:

[image: img]

This is from the Storyboard:

[image: img]

Anyone have any idea how to make these two buttons do the exact same action? Is it possible to make multiple buttons do one action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually keep the backing `UIView`s and `UIViewController`s very thin in my applications and I create classes that do the actual heavy lifting. This makes for cleaner code and easier reuse.

```
class Player {
     static func play() { // Static makes it easier to call from every class, assuming you only play one song at a time
          // play logic goes here
     }
}

class MyView: UIView {
     @IBAction func play() { // connect in IB in your .xib
          Player.play()
     }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBAction func play() { // connect in IB in your storyboard
          Player.play()
     }
}
```

Comment: looks legit, I'm gonna try...

Comment: How did it go @Safeen Azad?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Departamento B. Well, I used a protocol instead of creating a class in order to get the data from child to parent. But as you mentioned above, I can use it to do the actual procedure and then use it in my classes.

Comment: That's a useful pattern as well in this case. It kind of depends how far the buttons are away from each other, passing delegate references can become pretty complicated if the two screens aren't very closely related.

Answer (score 1):

You need two IBAction methods in separate classes (for cell and for view controller). If you want to minimize repeating code try to make a special class with this functionality and then call its method in two IBAction methods.

Also you can take a look at Command design pattern for this purpose.